# Any equivalent feature of Spark RDD.persist(..) in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

Spark RDD.persist(..) can help avoid the duplicated RDD evaluation.

Is there the same feature in Flink?

Actually I would like to know if I code like the following, Flink will evaluate `dataStream` once or twice?

```
val dataStream = env.addSource(...).filter(...).flatMap(...)

val s1 = dataStream.keyBy(key1).timeWindow(...).aggregate(..)

val s2 = dataStream.keyBy(key2).timeWindow(...).reduce(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `persist` in Flink as a `DataStream` on which multiple operators are applied is evaluated once and replicates all outgoing messages to each downstream operator.

The program in your case is executed as

```
                                 /-hash-> keyBy(key1) -> ...
 Source -> Filter -> FlatMap ->-<
                                 \-hash-> keyBy(key2) -> ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!